# Space left inside a div when using svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a wave like effect by placing a svg inside a div with 100vh height. I dont know why its leaving out some space beneath it. here is my code. Please can anyone help.

```
<section>
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 1400 300" width="1400" height="300">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="_clipPath_opvL9ndJ4NqZlV9Rt63GU8zU3EpxMNg9"><rect width="1400" height="300"/></clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_opvL9ndJ4NqZlV9Rt63GU8zU3EpxMNg9)"><path d=" M -2 175 Q 323.155 38.535 552 108 C 780.845 177.465 1034.282 232.817 1157 215 Q 1279.718 197.183 1400 152 L 1398 302 L 0 298 L -2 175 Z " fill="rgb(255,153,0)"/></g>
  </svg>
</section>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;        
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

svg path {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jake2917/pen/varmVp)

Comment: The bottom of the SVG isn't straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio of the space doesn't match the aspect ratio of the SVG. You could use preserveAspectRatio="none" to allow the SVG to distort to fill its container.

```css
html,body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 
}

section{
  position:relative;
  background-color: red;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
 

}


svg{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
  
  
}

svg path{
  fill:#fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
 
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><!-- Generator: Gravit.io --><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 1400 300" width="1400" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="none"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_opvL9ndJ4NqZlV9Rt63GU8zU3EpxMNg9"><rect width="1400" height="300"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_opvL9ndJ4NqZlV9Rt63GU8zU3EpxMNg9)"><path d=" M -2 175 Q 323.155 38.535 552 108 C 780.845 177.465 1034.282 232.817 1157 215 Q 1279.718 197.183 1400 152 L 1398 302 L 0 298 L -2 175 Z " fill="rgb(255,153,0)"/></g></svg>
</section>

<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Or if you do want to maintain it use preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax" e.g.

```css
html,body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 
}

section{
  position:relative;
  background-color: red;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
 

}


svg{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
  
  
}

svg path{
  fill:#fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
 
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><!-- Generator: Gravit.io --><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 1400 300" width="1400" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_opvL9ndJ4NqZlV9Rt63GU8zU3EpxMNg9"><rect width="1400" height="300"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_opvL9ndJ4NqZlV9Rt63GU8zU3EpxMNg9)"><path d=" M -2 175 Q 323.155 38.535 552 108 C 780.845 177.465 1034.282 232.817 1157 215 Q 1279.718 197.183 1400 152 L 1398 302 L 0 298 L -2 175 Z " fill="rgb(255,153,0)"/></g></svg>
</section>

<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert for the help. now i understand.I made the graphic using the free online vector program - vectr. I have used the size 1400px * 300px. Can you please tell me what size should i use?